# Calling a function when the page is loaded from a posted form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

On my index.php page, I have a form which posts into a 3rd party newsletter system.
The page reloads index.php?mail&
Is there anyway I can do a check when the page is loaded AND that the form has been posted?  If it has, that it can call another function?

Thanks Chris

The code:

So what I'm hoping for is a sort of onload feature which will detect if the form name="subscribe" has been posted.  Then I call a function (which will be a popup div).
I can get there with a little help and can do a bit of php or javascript, maybe not program it but understand some of it.  don't have a clue with ajax

mailbar8 (where the actual form is located for the newsletter):

```
<?php include("globals.php"); ?>   
<form action="<?php echo $website.$relative_string;?>" name="subscribe" onsubmit="javascript:return checkEmail(this);" method="post">
  <div id="cell8" class="titlecell2"><h3>Email:</h3></div>
     <div id="cell9" class="inputcell2">
        <input type="text" class="inputfield2" name="email" value="Your Email..." id="email2" maxlength="255" onfocus="this.value='';">
     </div>
     <div id="cell10" class="textcell3">
       <input name="group" type="hidden" id="group[]" value="<?php echo $group; ?>">
       <input name="subscribe" id="sub" type="radio" value="true" checked>
       </span>Subscribe</p>
     </div>
     <div id="cell11" class="buttoncell">
        <button type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Join" id="submitButton2" button" onClick="javascript:myFunction();"/>
        <span>Join</span>
        </button>
     </div>
     <div id="cell8" class="textcell4">
       <input type="radio" name="subscribe" id="unsub" value="false">
       </span>Un-Subscribe</p>
     </div>
  </form>
```

The form name is subscribe, it checks the email entry is legit and then if it is redirects the user back to: http://www.allcoles.com/index.php?page=mail&

The index.php (this bit of code displays the mailbar8.php form):

```
<div id="guestArea"  class="siteAreas">
<div id="guestTitle" class="roundedTitle">Guests</div>
<div id="guestContent" class="roundedContent">
  <h4>Get Our Newsletter!</h4>
  <?php
                      $mailbar=8;
                      $group=1;
                      include("maillist/mailbar.php");
                       ?>
</div>
</div>
  <!-- End of User and Guest Areas -->
```

index.php (the popup div I want to load when the page is open and the form is posted, it has a js file but that's not important - the popup div currently works by a href link on www.allcoles.com):

```
<div id="toPopup"> 
    <div class="close"></div>
    <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
    <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->
      <h2 align="center">All Coles Newsletter System</h2>
      <h3 align="center">bringing News, Birthdays, Events and Invites to your mailbox!</h3>
      <hr align="center" width="75%">
      <p style="text-align:center"> <?php
            if(isset ($_GET['page']))
            {
                if ($_GET['page'] == "mail")
                {
                include("maillist/mailmain.php");
                }

                if ($_GET['page'] == "about")
                {
                include("about.php");
                }
            }else {
                print("THIS PRINT IS WHERE THE NEWSLETTER SAYS THAT THE EMAIL HAS BEEN SUBSCRIBED TO THE DATABASE, THIS POPUP DIV IS A NICE WAY TO SHOW THAT.  THIS BIT CHANGES IF THE USER IS ALREADY SUBSCRIBED, OR  ADDED OR REMOVED");
            }
        ?>  </p2>
        <hr align="center" width="75%">
        <p style="text-align:center; font-size: 12px;">
        <font style="text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;">TIP</font>
       : Remember to check your Junk Mail, and add 'administrator@allcoles.com' to your 
        <font style="text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold;">SafeSenders</font>
         list.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="loader"></div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

So ideally - when (http://www.allcoles.com/index.php?page=mail&) loads it recognises the form named subscribe which has been submitted and then calls a function.
for example the function:  formPosted();

The solution I came up with was (with the help from everyone):

```
<?php
if(isset ($_GET['page']))
{
if ($_GET['page'] == "mail")
{
echo "<script>window.alert('Found the reply!');var formPosted = true;</script>";
}
}
?>
<script>
if(formPosted) {
window.alert("popupclick!");
popupClick();
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you are posting the form with Ajax then you can use a simple callback on success.

Comment: Didn't someone just have an answer with `$.post()`? I was going to upvote it, but it's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something simple like this?

```
<?php

    if( /* check if form has been postet */ ) {
        $form_posted = true;
    } else {
        $form_posted = false;
    }
?>
```

and then...

```
<?php if($form_posted) : ?>
    <script>
        formPosted();
    </script>
<? endif ?>
```

Comment: OP wants to use JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: But he said, that the page reloads with an additional param. So why usind JS, when you can simply do it with PHP?

@user3329933: You should write more details on what you actually want to do.

Comment: I know. But you downvoted without even reading the question carefully. He said "The page reloads", so he can (and should) use PHP.

Comment: He is using a file called index.php so I am quite sure PHP can be used.

Comment: @NobleUplift Why criticize someone else's solution if you don't have one yourself?

Comment: Just saw that! Don't know how I missed it. Still, the OP is specifically asking for an Ajax solution.

Comment: @RPM The answer I would have posted was posted by someone else, but I believe it's been deleted... I'll see if I can remember it to repost it.

Comment: can you explain $form_posted, my form name is subscribe so would it be $subscribe ?

Comment: I also have no idea how to use Ajax.  It went completely over my head, I can use a bit of javascript or php but need some guidance.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dispatched = isset($_POST['dispatched']) ? 1 : 0;

if($dispatched) {
  // handle data
   echo "<script>var formPosted = true;</script>";

}
?>

<script>
 if(formPosted) {
   // do something
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You should add `<?php ?>` tags so that the OP will know what is PHP and what is JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts, how does it recognise the form?  Do I need to change $dispatched to $subscribe which is my form name.

Comment: Would it be possible to show me how to implement your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax:

```
var mail = ???;
$.post( "index.php", { mail : mail }, function( data ) {
    formPosted();
});
```

It's simple. It posts to the page you want with the parameter mail and then calls the function you want.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I'm not sure how I would put the Ajax into my index.php?  can you explain so I can try?

Comment: Can you post your index.php to your question?

Comment: I uploaded the important code, I'm sorry there's so much of it.  The newsletter system is a 3rd party script which is free to use.

Comment: I've seen questions with more code. I might not be able to look at it now. I'll get back to this when I can.